# mounting remote hard disk (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, remote, remote-access

I have a machine running Ubuntu 10.04.  I have a VPS (virtual private server) also running Ubuntu Linux. The VPS has a dedicated IP.

I want to have a setup, so that the directories on the VPS are accessible  on my HOME PC like a mounted drive.

That is I should be able to do things like  edit files on the VPS and copy/move files from/to my home PC to the VPS, as if the VPS was mounted on my box.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the server via `Places` | `Connect to Server...`, then the remote server will be accessible via `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: nice! that was simple... its a bit too slow (much slower than normal ssh...any way to speed up?).

Comment: @cool:  You can try *sshfs*, which allows you to mount an SSH server from the command line as if it were a local disk.  I'm not sure that it will be any faster, though.  Just run `sudo apt-get install sshfs` or locate it in Synaptic or the Software Center to install it. There are [instructions for using it](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) on the FUSE website.

Comment: @cool, @Patches: FYI, if you choose "SSH" in the "Connect to Server" dialog, then it will use exactly the same SFTP protocol as `sshfs` uses.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via NFS ([a guide](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s03.html)). Basically, you add the directories to /etc/exports on the server, along with the options and the IP address of your home PC, then you can add the remote shares to your /etc/fstab.

edit: I should add that this works well with a VPN. If you just want to connect to the server and copy files, you can just use sftp as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams mentioned.